# Animate an icon to another icon in android

Tags: android, animation, svg, android-vectordrawable

I'm using Android Studio and I want to use Material Theme in my app but my app is RTL and I want to create my own Toolbar and I want to create hamburger menu icon to arrow forward (svg icons selected from [Google Material Icons](https://design.google.com/icons/))

So I have no idea how should I write the animation file! Thanks guys for helping :)

Comment: Try to read this first http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/ and https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html...

Comment: Actually I don't want help for Navigation Drawer! I want to create a svg animation from two svg icons and set it for Navigation Drawer Button (Because of rtl problem in Toolbar)